# Convert double to struct tm

Tags: c++, time, standards, c++-chrono, seconds

I have a `double` containing seconds. I would like to convert this into a `struct tm`.

I can't find a standard function which accomplishes this. Do I have to fill out the `struct tm` by hand?

I just [accidentally asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000399/convert-double-to-time-t) about converting to a `time_t` and http://www.StackOverflow.com will not let me post unless I link it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MSalters answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31000758/2642059) is correct, but I thought I'd add a bit of detail on *how* you should convert to `time_t` and how you should convert to `tm`.

So given a number of seconds in `double input` you can use the **implementation dependent** method of casting:

```
const auto temp = static_cast<time_t>(input);
```

But since `time_t` is implementation defined there is no way to know that this is a primitive that can simply be cast to. So the guaranteed method would be to use the chrono library's **implementation independent** method of converting:

```
const auto temp = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(chrono::system_clock::time_point(chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(chrono::duration<double>(input))));
```

The conversion options are discussed in more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50495821/2642059 but once you have obtained your `time_t` through one of these methods you can simply use [`localtime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime) to convert `temp` to a `struct tm`.

```
const auto output = *localtime(&temp);
```

Note the dereference is important. It will use the default copy assignment operator so `output` is captured by value, which is essential because:

> The structure may be shared between `std::gmtime`, `std::localtime`, and `std::ctime`, and may be overwritten on each invocation.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you accidentally asked the right question before. Convert `double` to `time_t`, and then convert that to a `struct tm`. There's no subsecond field in `struct tm` anyway.

Comment: Is there a function to do that conversion? Looks like I need to choose between [`localtime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime) and [`gmtime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/gmtime). Which one should I prefer?

Comment: @JonathanMee: `localtime` if you want local time and `gmtime` if you want GMT (UTC). Fairly obvious, really.

Comment: To complete this answer, you may want to mention that the function that does the conversion of `time_t` to `struct tm` is [`mktime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/).

Comment: @MSalters So `struct tm` and `time_t` both use the same epoch? I assume that's true but I can't seem to find support for it anywhere.

Comment: @JonathanMee: No, `struct tm` uses `1900` as its epoch whereas the epoch of `time_t` is unspecified. Why do you care?

Comment: @MSalters Well I just have an arbitrary number of hours, minutes, and seconds that I want to manipulate using `put_time` (for which I need my seconds in a `struct tm`.) If they don't share the same epoch and I just dump 320 into a `time_t` and then use `localtime` to put that into a `struct tm`; it the `struct tm` going to contain 5 minutes and 20 seconds? I just don't want the epoch discrepancy because I just dumped an arbitrary number into the `time_t` to give me unreliable results in my `struct tm`.

Comment: @JonathanMee: That won't work - `struct tm` is a time **point** not a time **duration**. 13 hours duration is **not** "1:00 PM"

Comment: @MSalters Ummm... seems like you are arguing the difference between a point and a vector. If it takes me 13 hrs to emotionally recover from a down-vote, that is a duration, but it is also a point in time given an arbitrary start time. What's more, I can measure that duration starting at the `struct tm` epoch and then I'll have a point which also indicates duration.

Comment: @JonathanMee: The new <chrono> stuff explicitly names it `std::chrono::time_point` and `std::chrono::duration`. I'm indeed arguing the difference because that's how C++ models time. As for the `struct tm` epoch, be aware that it probably isn't expressible as a `time_t` since its usual epoch is 1-1-1970 00:00 UTC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81388/discussion-between-jonathan-mee-and-msalters).

Answer (score 2):

For grins, using [this `chrono`-based header-only library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html):

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    auto recovery_time = 320.023s;  // Requires C++14 for the literal 's'
    std::cout << make_time(duration_cast<milliseconds>(recovery_time)) << '\n';
}
```

outputs:

```
00:05:20.023
```

The object returned by `make_time` has getters if you want to query each field:

```
constexpr std::chrono::hours hours() const noexcept {return h_;}
constexpr std::chrono::minutes minutes() const noexcept {return m_;}
constexpr std::chrono::seconds seconds() const noexcept {return s_;}
constexpr precision subseconds() const noexcept {return sub_s_;}
```

You don't need to choose `milliseconds`.  You could choose any precision you want from `hours` to `picoseconds` (if you also supply a type alias for `picoseconds`).  For example:

```
std::cout << make_time(duration_cast<seconds>(recovery_time)) << '\n';
```

Outputs:

```
00:05:20
```

Comment: It's not exactly an answer to the question but it does so much more! This is so pretty I might cry. I know this is your code that you've worked hard on but please tell me you've put this up for standardization?

Comment: No, but you are welcome to use it in your code.  It might eventually be put up for standardization, but before that can happen, you and 1000 other programmers need to not only use it, but vocally support it.

Comment: I've been keeping my eye on [P0355](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0355r0.html) I did have a question: "`puttime` ignores `iomanip` formatters, do your library's stream operators respect formatters?" (http://stackoverflow.com/q/40132424/2642059)

Comment: @JonathanMee:  Yes, `std::chrono::format` returns a `string` and thus when you stream it, `setw` and `left`/`right` are respected.  Fwiw, there will be an update to p0355r0 appearing any day now.  Here is a draft preview of that update:  https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/d0355r1.html

Comment: Exciting! I think I'll get as much use of this as I'm going to get out of `filesystem` (which is to say a lot of use.) Would you be interested in answering [my linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40132424/2642059) about how your library would solve my issue? I think that would mean more than my recommendation of your library.