# How can I Format Width in puttime?

Tags: c++, formatting, width, strftime, iomanip

Let's say that I want to print something simple like this table:

```
January   1
February  2
March     3
April     4
May       5
June      6
July      7
August    8
September 9
October   10
November  11
December  12
```

I'd like to accomplish this like:

```
for(tm i{ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 }; i.tm_mon < 12; ++i.tm_mon) cout << put_time(&i, "%-9B") << i.tm_mon + 1 << endl;
```

Unfortunately `puttime` doesn't seem to allow me to use field flags in it's format fields. Additionally this `puttime` doesn't seem to play nice with `setw`.

Is my only option to do `strftime` and then use that with `setw`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [header-only library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) that respects the I/O manipulators:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    auto m = jan;
    do
    {
        cout << left << setw(10) << format("%B", sys_days{m/1/1}) << right
             << unsigned(m) << '\n';
    } while (++m != jan);
}
```

You can try this out yourself by pasting the above code into this [wandbox link](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/FyeHIhAg2dniVu0W).

```
January   1
February  2
March     3
April     4
May       5
June      6
July      7
August    8
September 9
October   10
November  11
December  12
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will also work

```
for(tm i{ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 }; i.tm_mon < 12; ++i.tm_mon)
    {
        std::stringstream oss;
        oss << std::put_time(&i, "%B");
        string str = oss.str();
        cout << std::setiosflags(std::ios::left) << setw( 10 )  << str << setw( 2 ) << i.tm_mon + 1 << endl;
    }
```